# CoCreateInstance("CLSID") hangs up when code moved to IIS

Tags: c#

I have been trying to resolve this issue for sometime now but yet to succeed.

Scenario:
1) We have a web app developed in asp.net MVC and this in turn calls a Winforms exe for  drawing and printing docs.

2) Winforms exe uses third party DLL's for drawing and printing the docs.

3)Everything works fine when the code is run from VS 2015. But when the code is published to IIS, when the exe gets called but at the stage when the COM object is initialized using

(ThirdPartyControl)ThirdPartyControl.CoCreateInstance("{value}") code just hangs up and no exception is thrown.

Comment: Parts of your question are a bit ambiguous.  For example "Everything works fine when the code is run from VS 2015" - is the code in question the Winforms exe or the MVC web app?  Similarly it isn't clear how your MVC app "calls" the Winform exe.  We can guess what "call" might mean but we could  guess wrong.  You improve your chances of getting a helpful answer when you ask a well formed question.  You might find the advice in [ask] and [mcve] useful.

Comment: Sorry guys, apologies for the confusion.Code mentioned above breaks in the exe and the mvc app calls the exe via System.Diagnostics.Process class.

Comment: If I'm understanding this the Winform exe works correctly when it is executed from within Visual Studio but not when it is launched by the MVC app.  You might try executing the MVC app from Visual Studio with the debugger configured for mixed mode.  That should allow you to attach the debugger to the Winform exe after it has been launched.  Which might tell you something.

Comment: You might also think about identity and security.  When you run the Winform from Visual Studio it will be running with the Interactive User's identity (the currently logged on user).  When the MVC app launches the Winform it will run as some other identity - either inherited from the MVC app or specified by you in ProcessStartInfo.  Different identities might explain different behaviours.

Comment: It's not specified in the question, but is the app running on a different computer or OS when it's published to your IIS server? Is it possible the COM CLSID you're referencing is installed on your development machine but not on a test or production machine, so the CLSID lookup is failing?

Comment: exe works fine when it is run via mvc web app using VS 2015.The issue happens when we deploy the MVC code to IIS and try to run the web app from IIS. While debugging I could see the code just hanging up at (ThirdPartyControl)ThirdPartyControl.CoCreateInstance("{value}").

Comment: APP is deployed to IIS on my PC and also com the com is installed on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add this as a comment, but unfortunately my rep is too low.  Take a look at the user identity that the IIS process/application pool runs as.  It's possible that you as the user have installed the winform application into a directory that the identity does not have access to.  To test this quickly you could change the identity of the IIS user using your credentials and if that works, change it back and grant permissions to the original IIS user

Oh also if the winform application is 32 bit, make sure that 32 bit compatibility is turned on

Comment: In IIS app pool the identity is already set to use my credentials.Web app in IIS is able to invoke the exe but hangs up while trying to initialize the COM instance, though everything works fine when the web app calls the exe from VS 2015.

Comment: [Running Winforms From Services Non-Interactively](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-32-and-64-bit-Archite)
I should have also thought of this sooner.  When you start an application from visual studio, you're running the application as an interactive user.  IIS is a service that should not have access to user interactive components.  You can circumvent this, see the above post. If the COM component requires a UI window it may be failing because of this.

Comment: I'm not sure the post you suggested will work in my case.Since I'm not calling any service just calling an exe developed in WinForms.

Comment: IIS is a service